# Qt: How to detect which version of OpenGL is being used?

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5

There are several ways that Qt can use OpenGL: desktop (native), ANGLE, ES... and now there's 'dynamic' which can choose at runtime. Within an app, is there a way that you can detect which one is in use? Either within C++ or within QML?

e.g. something equivalent to the [global declarations](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html) that let you detect OS

Comment: `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`?

Comment: Generally speaking, you would use "dynamic" when you explicitly *do not care*. That is, you're writing to the lowest common denominator between ANGLE and desktop GL. So why exactly would you need to ask this question?

Comment: I have a Qt Quick 2 app. I'm encountering Intel graphics driver issues on a couple of PCs. This typically suggests "desktop", but I'm doing tests with a pre-built Qt binary (Qt 5.70 for Windows 32-bit, MinGW 5.3.0) which should be using ANGLE. I wanted to write a tiny program to confirm which version it's actually using.

Comment: Intel usually means "upgrade the drivers". You can figure out which context version you've got in many ways: the aforementioned `GL_VERSION`; using `OpenGLInfo` in Qt Quick itself; using `QOpenGLContext::openGLModuleType()`.

Comment: See also here for an explanation and how to use a blacklist for ANGLE/OpenGL depending on the GPU: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#dynamically-loading-graphics-drivers

Comment: @peppe Both your responses are very helpful. I had tried upgrading the drivers but they were already up-to-date. Is there a global way to force use of ANGLE on all Windows devices? If not, does the QT_OPENGL_BUGLIST variable get set within the .pro file? And can you provide an example?

Comment: *Is there a global way to force use of ANGLE on all Windows devices?* You could just rebuild Qt with only ANGLE support, or if you want to use dynamic builds, set `Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES` before creating a Q(Gui)Application.

Comment: @peppe Thanks for some excellent answers. Do you want to write them up as an 'answer'? Ideally covering my 'how to detect' question but ideally also straying into 'how to enforce'. You'll get my vote!

Comment: I found this link helpful:
http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/18/opengl-implementation-qt-quick-app-using-today/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To detect the OpenGL version

- in QML, there is `OpenGLInfo`
- in C++, there is `QOpenGLContext::openGLModuleType()`
- in the OpenGL C++ library, there is `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`
- see also [Qt blog article: Which OpenGL implementation is my Qt Quick app using today?](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/18/opengl-implementation-qt-quick-app-using-today/)

If you want to enforce a particular OpenGL version

- set the option in software (see code example below)

  - for desktop/native, either set the environment variable `QT_OPENGL` to `desktop` or set the application attribute to `Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL`
  - for ANGLE, either set the environment variable `QT_OPENGL` to `angle` or set the application attribute to `Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES`
  - for software rendering, either set the environment variable `QT_OPENGL` to `software` or set the application attribute to `Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL`
- create a static build of Qt using the `configure` options to set the implementation of OpenGL you want (but be mindful of the [Qt licensing rules](https://www1.qt.io/licensing/))

  - for desktop/native, include `-opengl desktop`
  - for ANGLE, **don't** include an `-opengl` option; that's because it is the default
  - there is also `-opengl dynamic` which lets Qt choose the best option. This was introduced in Qt 5.4. If you want this option but don't need a static build for any other reason, there's no need to create a static build, as the prebuilt binaries use this option since Qt 5.5.
  - there are also other variants that you can explore at [Qt for Windows - Requirements](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html). Although this is a Windows-specific page, much of the information about configuring OpenGL for Qt is contained here. (Probably because most of the OpenGL rendering issues are on the Windows platform!)

### Code example

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
//...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Set the OpenGL type before instantiating the application
    // In this example, we're forcing use of ANGLE.

    // Do either one of the following (not both). They are equivalent.
    qputenv("QT_OPENGL", "angle");
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);

    // Now instantiate the app
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    //...

    return app.exec();
}
```

*(thanks to **peppe** for the initial answers in the comments above and thanks to user12345 for the Blog link)*

Comment: glGetString(GL_VERSION) returns 0 on one of my machines (with Intel HD 3000) and OpenGL fails to show although another graphics card OpenGL test app displays a rendered scene. What can I do?

Comment: I also have the Intel HD 3000 with win10 (driver 9.17.10.3347 10-31-2013) and the only way to make my QML app work without a crash was to download the opengl32.dll of the mesa software renderer from here: https://fdossena.com/?p=mesa/index.frag
I just copied the opengl32.dll next to my qml_app.exe and finally it ran without crashing.

Comment: I've also tried the newer driver 9.17.10.4229 5-26-2015 which crashes as well.