# Qt+CUDA+OpenGL, share CUDA context with QOpenGLContext

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, cuda

I have a Qt program, which using `QOpenGLContext` for rendering.
Now I want to use `CUDA` to process image without extracting image to host.

If I use `(QT += core gui opengl)`, without using `QOpenGLContext`, I will use `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage` and map `OpenGL` to `CUDA` and everything works fine.

But, when I use [qputenv("QT_OPENGL", "angle");](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021681/qt-how-to-detect-which-version-of-opengl-is-being-used) (to setup `QOpenGLContext`) - even calling `cudaGLGetDevices(&glDeviceCount, glDevices, glDeviceCount, cudaGLDeviceListAll);` gives rubbish - meaning the `CUDA` context not the same as `QOpenGLContext`.

**How can I setup CUDA context to be the same as QOpenGLContext?**
I have read [about CUDA context](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__CTX.html), e.g `cuCtxCreate ( CUcontext* pctx, unsigned int  flags, CUdevice dev` 
but it seems to me, that there no such option.
**Maybe there are another solution, if I have to use `QOpenGLContext`?**