# QML Text sometimes skips rendering some characters

Tags: qt, qml, text-rendering

I have an application where I display the time on the screen. It works well except very rarely it sometimes does not render the time fully and skips rendering a number. For example if time is "11:07", it would render "11:0 " or "1 :07". I know it's a rendering problem because it fixes itself when the time changes and I can't recreate it by force setting the same time. Also I have the time in another screen in much smaller font, and I never see this issue there. I suspect it's something to do with rendering text in a large fontSize that causes this problem.

I tried creating the duplicate of my time text and using `TextMetrics` for both time text elements and compare their widths. If their widths are different, I assume that it did not render fully. I don't think this would actually work tho since it seems like the width of the elements would be the same, even if they don't render fully. I looked into `SafeText` but that does not work for my constraints. I am using NativeRendering since my font size is big (> 200px). Here is a MRE:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {

    width: 1024
    height: 600
    visible: true
    property string time: Qt.formatTime(new Date(),"hh:mm")

    onTimeChanged: {
        if(timeText.width !== timeTextDuplicate.width || timeMetric.width !== timeMetricDuplicate.width) {
            console.log("They are not the same")
            // redraw time
            time = ""
            time = Qt.formatTime(new Date(),"hh:mm")
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: root
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"

        Text {
            id: timeText
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            font.pixelSize: 200
            color: "white"
            text: time
        }

        TextMetrics {
            id: timeMetric
            text: timeText.text
            font: timeText.font
        }

        Text {
            id: timeTextDuplicate
            font: timeText.font
            text: timeText.text
            visible: false
        }

        TextMetrics {
            id: timeMetricDuplicate
            text: timeTextDuplicate.text
            font: timeTextDuplicate.font
        }

        Timer {
            id: timer
            interval: 60000
            repeat: true
            running: true
            onTriggered: time = Qt.formatTime(new Date(),"hh:mm")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output I get after setting `QSG_RENDERER_DEBUG=render`

```
Renderer::render() QSGAbstractRenderer(0x7f52702a63d0) "rebuild: full"
Rendering:
 -> Opaque: 1 nodes in 1 batches...
 -> Alpha: 6 nodes in 3 batches...
 - 0x7f52702be8a0 [  upload] [noclip] [opaque] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0
 - 0x7f52702be710 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    4  Vertices:    56  Indices:    84  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x7f52702be240 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [unmerged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0
 - 0x7f52702bdd70 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 -> times: build: 0, prepare(opaque/alpha): 0/0, sorting: 0, upload(opaque/alpha): 0/0, render: 0
Renderer::render() QSGAbstractRenderer(0x7f5270006190) "rebuild: full"
Rendering:
 -> Opaque: 2 nodes in 1 batches...
 -> Alpha: 19 nodes in 17 batches...
 - 0x7f52700d50a0 [  upload] [noclip] [opaque] [  merged]  Nodes:    2  Vertices:     8  Indices:    12  root: 0x0
 - 0x7f52700d18a0 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0 opacity: 0.2
 - 0x7f52702c5ad0 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:   152  Indices:   232  root: 0x0 opacity: 0.2
 - 0x7f52702c59e0 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [unmerged]  Nodes:    2  Vertices:   184  Indices:   280  root: 0x0
 - 0x7f52702c62c0 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [unmerged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0
 - 0x7f52702fdc90 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:    32  Indices:    48  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x7f527030db10 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [unmerged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0
 - 0x7f52702c6040 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:    96  Indices:   144  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x7f52702c5dc0 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [unmerged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0
 - 0x7f52700d5360 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:    84  Indices:   126  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x7f52700c8150 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x7f52702f0730 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x7f52702c0ce0 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:    16  Indices:    24  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x7f52702c5f00 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    2  Vertices:   184  Indices:   284  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x7f52702c5cb0 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x7f52702c5bc0 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     8  Indices:    12  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x7f52702c5800 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:     4  Indices:     6  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 - 0x7f52702c58f0 [  upload] [noclip] [ alpha] [  merged]  Nodes:    1  Vertices:    48  Indices:    72  root: 0x0 opacity: 1
 -> times: build: 0, prepare(opaque/alpha): 0/0, sorting: 0, upload(opaque/alpha): 0/0, render: 0
```

I understand this could be a problem with the graphics card or QML itself, but is there anything I could do to detect that this has happened? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I use `TextMetrics` slightly differently. I built a `BigText` component that chooses the largest value for `font.pixelSize` so that your text will fit but will not exceed the bounding rectangle. It does this by:

1. Looking at the `width` and `height` of the bounding rectangle
2. Looking at the `TextMetrics` `width` and `height` for a "small" pixel size
3. Calculate a scale factor to multiply the "small" pixel size so that the text will fit nicely in the bounding rectangle

The other point I would like to make is in your code, you set `TextMetrics` font as follows:

```
        TextMetrics { // ...
            font: timeText.font
        }
```

I have found this can screw things up as you're no longer using the original `font` that came with `TextMetrics`. I have found it safer to copy the font properties you need, e.g.

```
        TextMetrics { // ...
            font.family: timeText.font.family
        }
```

To see these concepts in in action, I changed your application by (1) increasing the frequency of your timer from `1 minute` to `1 second`. Change the time format from "hh:mm" to "hh:mm:ss".

Whilst running this app, try resizing the window and note the text font dynamically changes.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    id: page
    property double time: Date.now()
    //property string timeString: Qt.formatDateTime(new Date(time), "hh:mm")
    property string timeString: Qt.formatDateTime(new Date(time), "hh:mm:ss")
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        BigText {
            backgroundColor: "black"
            color: "white"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            Layout.preferredWidth: page.width / 2
            Layout.preferredHeight: page.height / 2
            text: timeString
        }
        RowLayout {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            Button {
                Layout.preferredWidth: height
                text: "-"
                //onClicked: slider.value -= 60000
                onClicked: slider.value -= 1000
            }
            Slider {
                id: slider
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                from: hhmm(0, 0, 0)
                to: hhmm(23, 59, 59)
                value: Date.now()
                function hhmm(hh, mm, ss) {
                    let d = new Date();
                    d.setHours(hh);
                    d.setMinutes(mm);
                    d.setSeconds(ss);
                    return d.getTime();
                }
                onValueChanged: {
                    autoButton.checked = false;
                    time = value;
                }
            }
            Button {
                Layout.preferredWidth: height
                text: "+"
                //onClicked: slider.value += 60000
                onClicked: slider.value += 1000
            }
        }
        Button {
            id: autoButton
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            text: qsTr("Auto")
            checkable: true
            Component.onCompleted: checked = true
        }
    }
    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 1000
        repeat: true
        running: autoButton.checked
        onTriggered: time = Date.now()
    }
}

// BigText.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Text {
    id: bigText
    width: 200
    height: 100
    color: "black"
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    property color backgroundColor: "white"
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: backgroundColor
        z: -1
    }
    property TextMetrics tm: TextMetrics {
        font.pixelSize: 10
        font.family: bigText.font.family
        text: bigText.text
    }
    font.pixelSize: tm.font.pixelSize * Math.min(bigText.width / tm.width, bigText.height / tm.height) * 0.9
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unless I misunderstood your solution, I think my question is a little different. My problem is not making the text fit on the screen or to avoid clipping, my problem is specifically with rendering. I sometimes see time as "11: 7" when it's "11:07". I know it's a rendering problem because it fixes itself when the time changes and I can't recreate it by force setting the same time. Also I have the time in another screen in much smaller font, and I never see this issue there.

Comment: @EvanKrause I see, are you on Windows? Are you on Qt5 or Qt6? Perhaps it's your OpenGL support and your graphics card driver that's an issue. You can try updating your graphics driver and/or changing your rendering engine (e.g. between ANGLE to OpenGL). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021681/qt-how-to-detect-which-version-of-opengl-is-being-used

Comment: In particular look at explorative troubleshooting by setting the `QT_OPENGL` environment variable with values `desktop`, `angle`, or `software` prior to running your app.

Comment: I'm on Linux using Qt5.15.0 with OpenGL 4.6. I can try changing the rendering engine, but since this happens so rarely, it might take weeks or longer to even notice a difference. How would I know that the problem has been solved? Is there a way to detect rendering issues? I have render logging turned on but so far I haven't seen anything out of the usual.

Comment: Right now, it's hard for you to repro because (1) the changes occur on a 60 minute Timer, (2) the text is also set by the Timer. To make it easier to reproduce, you should do a "functional test" by swapping out the Timer for UI/UX control such as ComboBox, Slider, Spinner, or Tumbler. That way, you can manufacture the problematic test cases on demand. I've updated the answer to show how you may swap out the Timer for such as unit test.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, I'll try that and see if I can repro it more often. Thanks!